# Need mysql query to get students marks total or sum of the 4column(telegu ,maths,social,english) in single query

Tags: sql

```
Name         Null? Type          
------------ ----- ------------- 
SNO                NUMBER(38)    
STUD_ID            VARCHAR2(26)  
STUDENT_NAME       VARCHAR2(128) 
DATEOFBIRTH        VARCHAR2(26)  
CLASS              NUMBER(38)    
SECTION            VARCHAR2(26)  
GENDER             VARCHAR2(26)  
TELEGU             VARCHAR2(26)  
MATHS              VARCHAR2(26)  
SOCIAL             VARCHAR2(26)  
ENGLISH            VARCHAR2(26)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please consider posting an explanation of your problem, what you have attempted and the results.

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Are you using Oracle, or MySQL?

Comment: Why would you want to take the sum of a column that is declared as a string?  You should fix your data model.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT student, (SUM(TELEGU)+SUM(MATHS)+SUM(SOCIAL)....+SUM(ENGLISH)) AS Total
 FROM your_table
 GROUP BY student
```

Comment: hi, can some one help in the sql query, i need to add   ( Telegu+Maths+English+social=   result)   this the output . t try but i got errors